# How do I resolve the semaphore timeout expired issue, with SerialPort in .NET 7 C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-core, serial-port, semaphore

While writing and reading to a virtual serial port in my C# ASP.NET Core 7 Web API project.

I occasionally get an `IOException`, when this issue occurs I seem to be unable to recover the serialport without shutting down the connected device.

Stack trace of the exception

> System.IO.IOException: The semaphore timeout period has expired. : 'COM7'
>
> at System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
> at System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.Write(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Int32 timeout)
> at System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)

Instantiating of the `SerialPort` class

```
if (_serialPort == null && SerialPort.GetPortNames().Contains(poortNaam))
{
    _serialPort = new SerialPort(_poortNaam, _baudrate, _parity, _dataBits, _stopBits);
    _serialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;
    _serialPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
    _serialPort.ReadBufferSize = 8192;
    _serialPort.WriteBufferSize = 8192;
    _serialPort.RtsEnable = true;

    Semaphore.Wait();

    if (_serialPort.IsOpen)
    {
        _serialPort.Close();
        Thread.Sleep(250);
    }

    _serialPort.Open();

    Thread.Sleep(500);

    Semaphore.Release();
}
```

Inside my writing method:

```
try
{
     _serialPort.DiscardInBuffer();
     _serialPort.DiscardOutBuffer();

     if (!_serialPort.IsOpen)
     {
         _serialPort.Open();
         Thread.Sleep(250);
     }

     Trace.Write("Verstuur: ");

     foreach (var item in frame)
     {
         Trace.Write($"{item},");
     }

     _serialPort.Write(frame, 0, frame.Length);
 }
 catch (IOException ioe)
 {
     Trace.WriteLine(ioe.ToString());
     _serialPort.Close();
     Thread.Sleep(500);
     _serialPort.Open();
     Thread.Sleep(500);
     _serialPort.Write(frame, 0, frame.Length);
 }
```

This is my reading method:

```
byte incomingByte

while(!timeout && !MessageStop)
{
    try
    {
        int IncomingBytes = _serialPort.BytesToRead;

        for (int i = 0; i < IncomingBytes ; i++)
        { 
            incomingByte = (byte)_serialPort.ReadByte();
            IncomingBytesList.Add(incomingByte );

            if (incomingByte == Ex || (incomingByte == Nak && IncomingBytes == 1) || (incomingByte == Ak && IncomingBytes == 1))
            {
                MessageStop = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ioe)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(ioe.Message);
        _serialPort.Close();
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        _serialPort.Open();
        Thread.Sleep(200);
    }
}
```

I assume that this issue occurs after another issue that causes the helper thread of the `SerialPort` class to get stuck, and triggering the timeout.

1. How do I best handle/recover from this issue?
2. How do I avoid causing this issue?

What I've tried already:

1. I've used `SemaphoreSlim` to limit the threads accessing this code.
2. Attempted to open and close the serial port with delays between and after.
3. Attempted to overwrite the `SerialPort` instance with a new one.

Comment: It would be helpful if you post the entire code fragment showing how you instantiate and manage the _serialPort object

Comment: Try to set `_serialPort.DtrEnable = TRUE;` before making a connection and see if it helps.

Comment: I've just tested this but it seems to make no difference.

Comment: Why have you chosen to use a _semaphore_?

Comment: Try `serialPort.DtrEnable = true;` as another commenter mentioned. Also subscribe to [SerialPort.PinChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.pinchanged?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0) and get rid of the _semaphore_.